# Call many setters with one object

Tags: php

I try to call many setters from one entity, but I have error NULL object.

When I do this :

```
$appEventUser
    ->setApiToken($apiToken)
    ->setCreationDate(new \DateTime())
    ->setSubType('SIGNED')
    ->setSignedType('IN');
```

I have this error :

```
Call to a member function setSignedType() on a non-object
```

But, if I try the following code it's ok :

```
$appEventUser
    ->setApiToken($apiToken)
    ->setCreationDate(new \DateTime())
    ->setSubType('SIGNED');

$appEventUser->setSignedType('IN');
```

Comment: Are returning `$this` in your setters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the entity in `setSubType` setter :

```
public function setSubType($subtype){
    $this->subType = $subtype ;

    return $this // this line is missing 
}
```

You get that message because `setSubType()` returns nothing ( or NULL technically speaking )  thus calling a method on 'nothing' is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

If `setSubType()` does not return `$this`, you won't be able to call other methods on that same object after that.

Answer (score 0):

Method `setSubType` should return `$this` if you want to chain methods.